# How to remove duplicates in CTE from VARIABLES and TEMPORARY TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was looking for this solution in internet and none of them worked properly.
I decided to create variables, then accommodates it in the user defined function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Top10CustomerByCategoryInYear
(
    @Category varchar(MAX),
    @StartYear int,
    @EndYear int
)
RETURNS @CustomerTop10TableByCategoryInYears TABLE
(
    [Customer Name]  VARCHAR(MAX),
    [Category] VARCHAR(MAX),
    Sales int,
    Year int
)
AS
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @CustomerTop10TableByCategoryInYears
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT TOP 10 WITH TIES
        [Customer Name], 
        [Category], 
        SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY [Customer Name]) as Sales,
        YearOfOrderDate as [Year]
    FROM [Project4].[dbo].[SuperStore]
    WHERE [Category] = @Category AND YearOfOrderDate BETWEEN @StartYear AND @EndYear
    ORDER BY Sales DESC 
    RETURN;
END
GO
```

It works properly, because for example I am able to return the top 10 Customer in the Furniture Category in 2011 and 2012

```
SELECT *
FROM Top10CustomerByCategoryInYear('Furniture',2011,2011)
SELECT * 
FROM Top10CustomerByCategoryInYear('Furniture',2012,2012)
```

[image: The result]
[image: The result]

Then, I would like to have all records (2011-2014) in one Table. I decided to use CTE, then JOIN these Tables by Category:

```
WITH Furniture2011 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM Top10CustomerByCategoryInYear('Furniture',2011,2011)
), Furniture2012 AS (
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Top10CustomerByCategoryInYear('Furniture',2012,2012)
), Furniture2013 AS (
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Top10CustomerByCategoryInYear('Furniture',2013,2013)
),  Furniture2014 AS  (
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Top10CustomerByCategoryInYear('Furniture',2014,2014)
)
SELECT  DISTINCT *
FROM Furniture2011 F1
        JOIN Furniture2012 F2
        ON F1.Category = F2.Category
        JOIN Furniture2013 F3
        ON F1.Category = F3.Category
        JOIN Furniture2014 F4
        ON F1.Category = F4.Category
```

Unfortunately there are a lot of duplicates:

[[image: Duplicates3]

I tried a lot of solutions from my mind and internet and unfortunately these did not work.
I was wondering if it is possible to combine these Tables using UDF/Variables, TEMP TABLE and finally CTE.
Could you please tell me if it is possible?
If so, would you be so kind as to support me in modifying my codes in SQL to have the desired result without any duplicates?

I would appreciate it if you could advise me on it.

Comment: FYI, if you are using table value functions I **strongly** recommend you make them inline TVFs. Multi-line TVFs are notoriously slow.

Comment: You're looking for a `UNION` here since the individual data doesn't overlap. If for some reason you then want the data in columns instead of rows, and you can't get your client code to make that arrangement, you can pivot it.

Comment: @Larnu thank you for your comment!

Comment: @Jeroen thank you for this idea! I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an *inline* Table function taking a start and end year. Inline is faster than multi-statement.

Start with a virtual table of years, then `CROSS APPLY` the top 10 results for each year.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION Top10CustomerByCategoryInYear
(
    @Category varchar(MAX),
    @StartYear int,
    @EndYear int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

    WITH L0 AS (
        SELECT @StartYear - 1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Year
            FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS D(c)
    ),
    Years AS (
        SELECT * FROM L0 WHERE Year <= @EndYear
    )
    SELECT
        s.[Customer Name], 
        @Category AS [Category], 
        s.Sales,
        y.Year
    FROM Years y
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 10 WITH TIES
            [Customer Name],
            SUM(Sales) AS Sales
        FROM [dbo].[SuperStore] s
        WHERE [Category] = @Category
          AND y.Year = s.YearOfOrderDate
        GROUP BY [Customer Name]
        ORDER BY Sales DESC
    ) s;

GO
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer,  however your code does not work.. I have this problem: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Top10CustomerByCategoryInYear1, Line 35 [Batch Start Line 461]
Incorrect syntax near ')'. What is more, I do not understand the first CTE with a lot of numbers. Could you please simplify it little bit?

Comment: That is called an inline tally, @lukasz93 .

Comment: @lukasz93 Sorry missed off table alias `s`. An inline tally function generates a list of numbers, so I'm generating rows from `@StartYear` to `@EndYear`. See https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1

Comment: Thank you for it. It works, but I have the same result. I run this: Top10CustomerByCategoryInYear('Furniture',2011,2011) and I have the same result as previous one. Then, I combined these Tables by JOIN and I have the same result with a lot duplicates. Could you please instruct myself how to avoid these ones ?

Comment: I don't understand why you are joining. Just give it a start and end year 2011 and 2014, and execute it once

Comment: @Charlieface thank you for it! Now I have the same result as I would make it UNION. I would like to have table by table like I would do it using JOIN instead of UNION. Is it possible to make it? Should I PIVOT it now? Do you have any ideas of doing it?

Comment: Sounds like you want a pivot, yes. Probably easiest to do a mannual pivot by using `GROUP BY` and conditional aggregation `SUM(CASE WHEN...`

Comment: Would you be so kind as to write this code? It is difficult for me to write it because I am a beginner in it.